# Why does John Casey from Chuck have such admiration for President Ronald Reagan?

Tags: character, chuck

I'm not an American so someone from the US may be able to explain. Why does John Casey admire and keep photos of ex-President Ronald Reagan, I mean why that specific president, and not any other previous or current president?

[image: John Casey and Regan]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adam Baldwin was personally responsible for the development of the Casey character, a character with which he identifies strongly. The photo of Reagan is his own personal photo, he often tweets Reagan quotes, and he is due to play Reagan in an [upcoming film](http://freewayhome.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/adam-baldwin-to-play-ronald-reagan-in-historical-drama/). In an [interview with Big Hollywood](http://www.breitbart.com/Big-Hollywood/2012/01/27/BH-Interview--Adam-Baldwin-On-Saying-Farewell-to-Chuck--Being-Openly-Conservative-in-Hollywood), he talks about being openly conservative in Hollywood:

> I do take the responsibility of portraying a guy who’s serious about
>   protecting the nation and I am a serious patriot, an American Patriot.
>   I believe that without our military, fighting men and women, that our
>   country would have fallen long ago. But they didn’t allow that to
>   happen so I support and defend that in my civilian capacity as much as
>   I can. And I try to portray that as well as I can. So, I love the
>   military. I love weapons as tools of defending liberty, individual
>   liberty, and freedom. I believe in the Constitution. I believe in the
>   American founding documents, or as Madison or Adams called them,
>   America’s political scriptures, which are the Declaration of
>   Independence, the Constitution and the Bill of Rights...
>
> Casey defends, protects, serves America, which is what America’s
>   scriptures say, which is protect, secure life, liberty and the pursuit
>   of happiness. And, that’s what Casey, he is. You know, the folks (on
>   "Chuck") were accommodating to the fact that I brought a perspective
>   that they necessarily didn’t have in their life, or their creative
>   writing, that could make John Casey more authentic...
>
> **Did you keep the picture of Ronald Reagan that was in Casey’s apartment?** Well, that was mine. That was a copy I have, so I have
>   the original. Yes.

Answer (score 4):

It could be because Reagan was strongly anti-communist and lead a strong military policy during the cold war, two points which agree very well with John Casey.